# ThinkPad X220i appears to power on but won't start - no BIOS or beeps

Tags: boot, laptop, power, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad X220i laptop here (4-5 years old, out of warranty) that won't power on any more. Looking for any tips to get to the cause and repair it.

**The problem**: When you press the power button a few LEDs light up: the one around the power switch itself, the ones on the Caps Lock and Mute keys, the Bluetooth indicator, and the light on the top of the screen for lighting up the keyboard. The power switch and Bluetooth lights remain on, others go off. Nothing happens: screen never turns on (doesn't even flicker), no beeping noises, I can hear the CPU fan running quietly though.

**What I've tried**:

- It doesn't appear to be a broken screen - I plugged in an external monitor and got the same result.
- It doesn't appear to be the battery - I removed the battery and ran it from AC power only and got the same result. I've also tried the battery and not plugged into the wall, same result.
- It's not the hard drive - I've taken it out and put it in another laptop, boots fine.
- I've removed and re-settled the one stick of RAM that it has. Didn't help. Possibly this memory stick is the problem - I don't have another memory stick to try in its place (I could buy one). This is the only idea I have at the mo.

  I did try booting it without the RAM stick in (so no RAM) - again the screen didn't come on at all, but it gave a pattern of five beeps which I guess means "no memory".
- It doesn't seem to be overheating - it's not hot at all.

Things that may have caused whatever the problem is include:

- The laptop was recently dragged along the surface of a table pulling out the battery and causing sudden power loss. This corrupted the file system, OS wouldn't boot, but after repairing the file system it worked fine for a couple more weeks (and the hard drive  and filesystem are still working fine in another laptop).
- Laptop has been charged using power adapters from other ThinkPad laptops (an X230 and an X200 I think)

I suppose one possibility is that the laptop is just dead - some part of the motherboard has broken. Or it's the memory stick, replacing that may be worth a try. Thanks for any other suggestions!

Comment: If you get the diagnostic beeps with no RAM, it means it's getting into the POST.  If you don't get the single POST beep with RAM in, it means it isn't successfully finishing the POST.  However, anything the POST evaluates should produce beeps if it doesn't pass.  This suggests that the POST is reaching a point where it simply stops testing.  Maybe BIOS corruption?  Something that will cost you a couple of dollars to rule out, even though I can't conceive it would be the source of this problem: replace the CMOS battery.  If you've never done it, it is probably dead by now, anyway.

Comment: I've never replaced the CMOS battery, on this laptop or another. It's something I could try I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After replacing the memory stick - it boots!

So, a dodgy memory stick can apparently cause a ThinkPad x220i to turn on but do nothing - no screen, no beeping. Was working fine, then one day this memory stick went bad.

By the way, the laptop doesn't make any BIOS POST beeping noises - even when it does boot successfully. At least not when booting from a USB thumb drive, I haven't put the proper hard drive back in it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't even have to be faulty memory. If the memory is incorrectly seated in the slot this power on but not boot issue can happen. In that case it's sufficient to reseat the memory.